# Convert Pivot Table to Data Frame Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following pivot table:

```
 Date_TimeSpam  2016-01-01  2016-01-02      
Time_TimeSpam                                                                                   

00:15:00          36.0          92.0        
00:30:00          72.0          136.0       
00:45:00          80.0          88.0
```

How can I convert it to a normal pandas Data Frame?
The desire output is:

```
Date_TimeSpam  Time_TimeSpam   value

2016-01-01      00:15:00        36.0
2016-01-01      00:30:00        72.0
2016-01-01      00:45:00        80.0
2016-01-02      00:15:00        92.0
2016-01-02      00:30:00        136.0
2016-01-02      00:45:00        88.0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just `df.stack()`

Comment: `df.stack().swaplevel().reset_index(name='Value')`

Comment: @ansev Perfectly works, Thank you very much!

Comment: @ansev `df.T.stack().reset_index()` is a bit shorter :D